# Qt 5 causes gatekeeper block my app

Tags: macos, qt, frameworks

I use Qt 5 for my app on Mac, and since Apple released 10.9.5 and 10.10, my app is blocked by gatekeeper. It reports "XXX can't be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed". After some research I found [this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/47768) that explains the problem is Qt 5 frameworks, for example QtCore, QtGui, etc. The solution is reorganize the layout of those frameworks. I use python script to do this process and it all works well on my machine. When I run "spctl -a -t exec -vv MyApp.app", it reports accepted, this was rejected before.

Here is a link from Apple to explain about the layout.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html

But when I create the image (using hdiutil) and distribute it. It loses all the symbolic links in the app, which makes gatekeeper block it again with the same report.

Is there any way to get around this? Either use another way to create the image or another way to solve Qt framework layout problem.

Thanks in advanced.

Jerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find out what is the really problem.

It is not the hdiutil command that removes the symbolic links. It is python script I used, shutil.copytree. This copy tree or any other copy functions do deep copy, which substitutes the symbolic link to the object it points to.

An easiest way or alternative solution is use shutil.move if this is possible in your case.

Thanks,
Jerry